# Creating a data frame from inputs in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a shinny app where I can enter input from a sidebar panel to create a data frame on my second tabpanel called table. I am able to have 1 row of data but when I press my submit button it refresh these instead of adding another row. Thank you very much for your help.

Here is my code:

````
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Team"),
  tags$img(height = 100, width = 100,
           src = "Logo"),
    sidebarPanel(
    textInput(inputId = "date",
            label = "Date", 
            value = "yyyy/mm/dd"),
  textInput(inputId = "team",
            label = "Team Name", 
            value = "Team Name"),
  textInput(inputId = "pnumber",
            label = "Player Number", 
            value = "#"),
  selectInput("shot", "shot type:",
              list(`Shot Type` = list("wrist shot", "slap shot", "snap shot"))),
  selectInput("situation", "scoring opportunity:",
              list(`Green` = list("Double cross", "dot line pass"),
                   `Yellow` = list("2vs1", "same side quick"),
                   `Red` = list("clear", "wrap"))),
  submitButton("Add")),
  
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("Track", plotOutput(outputId = "hockeyplot")),
            tabPanel("Data", tableOutput(outputId = "table")),
            tabPanel("Chart", plotOutput(outputId = "chart")))),)
  

server <- function(input, output){
  Reactive_Var<-reactive({
    results=data.frame(Date = input$date, Team = input$team, Player = input$pnumber, ShotType = input$shot, Situation = input$situation)})
  observeEvent(input$Add, {df<- data.frame(Date = input$date, Team = input$team, Player = input$pnumber, ShotType = input$shot, Situation = input$situation)})
  output$table<-renderTable({
    Reactive_Var()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:

First, would use an `actionButton` instead of a `submitButton` (this is generally preferable). See [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html) for more information using action buttons.

Second, you can create an empty dataframe (as default) stored in `reactiveValues`. When the "Add" button is selected, a new row of data is added to this data frame with `rbind`.

Then, `renderTable` will show the updated `reactiveValues` data frame.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Team"),
  tags$img(height = 100, width = 100,
           src = "Logo"),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput(inputId = "date",
              label = "Date", 
              value = "yyyy/mm/dd"),
    textInput(inputId = "team",
              label = "Team Name", 
              value = "Team Name"),
    textInput(inputId = "pnumber",
              label = "Player Number", 
              value = "#"),
    selectInput("shot", "shot type:",
                list(`Shot Type` = list("wrist shot", "slap shot", "snap shot"))),
    selectInput("situation", "scoring opportunity:",
                list(`Green` = list("Double cross", "dot line pass"),
                     `Yellow` = list("2vs1", "same side quick"),
                     `Red` = list("clear", "wrap"))),
    actionButton("Add", "Add")),
  
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Track", plotOutput(outputId = "hockeyplot")),
    tabPanel("Data", tableOutput(outputId = "table")),
    tabPanel("Chart", plotOutput(outputId = "chart")))))


server <- function(input, output){
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    df = data.frame(
      Date = as.Date(character()),
      Team = character(),
      Player = character(),
      ShotType = character(),
      Situation = character()
    )
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$Add, {
    rv$df <- rbind(rv$df, data.frame(Date = input$date, 
                                     Team = input$team, 
                                     Player = input$pnumber, 
                                     ShotType = input$shot, 
                                     Situation = input$situation))
  })
  
  output$table<-renderTable({
    rv$df
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```